# Problem with query_posts for a custom taxonomy in theme options

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, theme-options

I am having some issues with querying the output of custom taxonomies in my theme options.

I have included what I think are the necessaries below.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

```
// Pull all the custom taxonomies into an array

$options_taxonomies = array();
$taxonomies_terms_obj = get_terms('portfolio_category');
foreach ($taxonomies_terms_obj as $taxonomy) {
    $options_taxonomies[$taxonomy->term_id] = $taxonomy->name;
}

// Select a Featured Homepage Category

$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Featured Homepage Category', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('Choose a category to feature on your homepage.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'homepage_feature',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $options_taxonomies);
}

//The query

if ( function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) :
    query_posts( 'cat=' . $homepage_feature = of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' ) . '&posts_per_page=3' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three things.

```
if ( function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) :
    query_posts( 'cat=' . $homepage_feature = of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' ) . '&posts_per_page=3' );
```

1. You have a syntax error. There is no `endif;`. Maybe that is a typo, but maybe not. If you are trying to write a one-line `if`, remove the colon.
2. Your title states "custom taxonomy". [`cat=` is for *categories*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), not [general taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). See the Codex.
3. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), not [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Assuming the rest of the code works, and assuming I am reading it right, your query should be:

```
if ( function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) {
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
            'field' => 'id', // or slug; I don't know which you have
            'terms' => of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' )
         )
     )
  );
  $my_qry = new WP_Query($args); 
}
```

Comment: This works but only displays a link to Home? and does not pull out the taxonomies as defined in the $options_taxonomies

Comment: `WP_query` does not display a link at all. It returns an Object. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had a syntax error on the if statement. 

Sorry, the taxonomies are being listed in my options.php fine, but wont work with the query. If I query an array using  get_categories it works fine?

If it helps my arrays are in a template named options.php with the query in front-page.php

Comment: Post the output from `of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' );`

Comment: Wow... that got scrambled. Sorry. Let me try again. Post the content of `var_dump(of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' ));`

Comment: ok, not sure i've done this right, but the output is

string(2) "46"

I just placed var_dump(of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' )); in the if statement ?

Comment: You need the `id` not the slug. There was a note in my code, which I've edited to use the `id`.

Comment: I have reposted this question with full code here: 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85572/problem-with-query-posts-for-a-custom-taxonomy-in-theme-options