# Cannot query custom post type taxonomy from theme options array

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, theme-options, tax-query

I am having no luck with querying a custom post type taxonomy from an array in theme options.

My full code is below, would be grateful for some feedback to get it working correctly as I cannot get this to work.

```
// Pull all the custom taxonomies into an array
// options.php

$options_taxonomies = array();
$taxonomies_terms_obj = get_terms('portfolio_category');
  foreach ($taxonomies_terms_obj as $taxonomy) {
$options_taxonomies[$taxonomy->term_id] = $taxonomy->name;
}

// Select a Featured Homepage Category

 $options[] = array(
'name' => __('Featured Homepage Category', 'options_framework_theme'),
'desc' => __('Choose a category to feature on your homepage.', 'options_framework_theme'),
'id' => 'homepage_feature',
'type' => 'select',
'options' => $options_taxonomies);
 }

// WP_Query and Loop
// front-page.php

<?php 

$num_cols = 3; // set the number of columns here

if ( function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) :

   $args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => of_get_option( 'homepage_feature' )
         )
     )
  );

  $my_qry = new WP_Query($args); 

  if (have_posts()) :
  for ( $i=1 ; $i <= $num_cols; $i++ ) :
  echo '<div id="col-'.$i.'" class="four columns entry-thumb">';
  $counter = $num_cols + 1 - $i;
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      if( $counter%$num_cols == 0 ) : ?>
      <!-- core post area; title, content, thumbnails, postmeta, etc -->
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-home', array('class' => 'image-fade')); ?></a>
<p class="entry-title-home"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
  <?php endif;
  $counter++;
endwhile;
rewind_posts();
    echo '</div>'; //closes the column div
endfor;
else:
   echo '<div class="four columns">Please create a post.</div>';
  endif;
  endif; rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: You should not have duplicated this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85572/problem-with-query-posts-for-a-custom-taxonomy-in-theme-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new query and assign it to `$my_qry`, but you never loop over those results. See the codex page for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), the loop has to reference your new query object:

```
$my_qry = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $my_qry->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_qry->have_posts() ) :
        $my_qry->the_post();
        // etc..
    endwhile;
endif;
```